# Problem with tensorflow running in a multithreading in python. The function works well without thread but not in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

I am doing object detection, I am using a free python library which can be found at this link:https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI(Which uses tensorflow and keras as backend).The problem is that the object detection function works well in a single python script.But when i call the same function in a thread(multithreading), i get a bunch of errors.After a few debugging, I saw that the thread fails to load the model that is,( detector.loadModel(detection_speed="flash")) which eventually works when call in main. Even trying to declare and pass the model as global results in error

I have also try to load the detection model in the same thread but in vain.
Here is my script:

---

```
import tensorflow as tf

#import for threading
import threading
import queue
#import for PIR
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
#import for camera 
from picamera import PiCamera
from PIL import Image
#import function objectDetect function from singularObjectDetection 
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
from singularObjectDetection import objectDetect

###function calling objectdetection function
def read():
    print("read "+ os.getcwd())
    execution_path = os.getcwd()
    detector = ObjectDetection()
    detector.setModelTypeAsTinyYOLOv3()
    detector.setModelPath(os.path.join(execution_path, "yolo-tiny.h5"))
    detector.loadModel(detection_speed="flash")
    custom = detector.CustomObjects(person=True, dog=True)
    while True:
         objectDetect("image1.jpg")

print("in main")
q=queue.Queue()
t2=threading.Thread(target=read,daemon=True)
t1.start()
```

---

Errors that i am getting:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1050, in _run
    subfeed, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=False)
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3488, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3567, in _as_graph_element_locked
    raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder_12:0", shape=(64,), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/threadfinal.py", line 57, in read
    detector.loadModel(detection_speed="flash")
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/imageai/Detection/__init__.py", line 213, in loadModel
    model.load_weights(self.modelPath)
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1166, in load_weights
    f, self.layers, reshape=reshape)
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 1058, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
    K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2470, in batch_set_value
    get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 887, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1053, in _run
    'Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: ' + e.args[0])
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder_12:0", shape=(64,), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating more than one graph, perhaps one graph per thread.

Instead of relying on TF's default implicit graph I recommend you create a graph and explicitly enter it with `with g.as_default():` on all threads you're creating.

Comment: Could you provide a code sample for this? I am experiencing the exact same issue. Works fine when defining 1 extra thread, but 2 it throws exception. Not sure how to incorporate Graphs into this.

Comment: The code sample is, at the top of your program, before any threads are created, do g = tf.get_default_graph(). Then, inside each thread, before doing anything, enter a "with g.as_default():" context. Note though that tf graph construction is not thread-safe.